# How to read contents of an external script/style?

Tags: javascript, css

I know that you can get and set the contents of a tag in the current page using "innerHTML".

However, I was wondering if there was a way to read (not execute, but reading the contents) an external script/style via the same way? Something like

```
<script id="dScript" src="url.js"></script>

//in real practice, this returns a blank
//what i need is to read url.js's contents
<script>
    var extScript = document.getElementById('dScript').innerHTML;
</script>
```

In the same context, how does LESS CSS read custom linked sheets? I know you can do it via AJAX but i'm trying to load contents using a script loader, effectively bypassing SOP using dynamic tags so AJAX is out of the question.

Comment: it returns blank because it's blank...

Comment: i know it's blank. that's just a sample. i wanted to know if there was a way to read the external script/sheet in a similar way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is a violation of the same-origin policy.  That's why JSONP executes a third-party script (it doesn't read it).

You might be able to do it with Cross Origin Resource Sharing, but as far as I know that would have to be AJAX.

Comment: so it's like i can apply external sheets/execute external scripts (JSONP/callback style), but not read them?

Answer (score 1):

I created a proxy server to do exactly what you are looking for. The API is called realJS (Resource Express Asynchronous Loader). It asynchronously loads any resource you want from any domain you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>REAL</title>
        <script data-src="http://realdotjs.appspot.com/loader.html" src="http://realdotjs.appspot.com/script/real.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("realJSLoaded", function (realJS) {
                realJS.load.paths.push("http://code.jquery.com/");
                realJS.load("jquery.js", loadScript);

                function loadScript(script) {
                    // do something with the script
                }
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

You can add as many paths as you want to `realJS.load.paths` and it will find the correct resource from the correct path. It supports commonJS module identifiers and abosolute URLs too.

Any kind of text or binary file can be loaded. However you have to handle the file returned correctly. Cheers. =)